# All possible strings from a given alphabet

Tags: python, combinations

I am trying to generate all possible strings of a specific length from a given alphabet (in the form of a list).

I tried using iterools methods(mainly itertools.product) but even though it worked for small lengths, it was, as expected, very expensive for, let's say n=100. I think I let it run for about 1 hour and it still wasn't finished.

What is the fastest way to achieve this in a reasonable time frame?

Comment: What do you mean by given alphabet?

Comment: let's say we have L=['a', 'b']. And we need all possible combinations of length 100 from L.

Comment: What would be a reasonable timeframe for generating e.g. `26 ** 100` combinations of characters? Even with a two-character alphabet (think binary!), there are `1,267,650,600,228,229,401,496,703,205,376` possible outputs. At 1ns per output, that's 2,900 times the age of the universe (thanks, [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2+**+100+ns)).

Comment: Have you calculated, how many combinations you generate with a length of 100?

Comment: Your output would be exponential order i.e. l^n where l is the max length of string alphabets and n is the size of list. So it is expected to take time

Comment: I have. As I said I know it is insanely expensive, but it is required for a task I have to do. That is why I'm looking for something to improve (if possible) speed.

Comment: There are 1,267,650,600,228,229,401,496,703,205,376 such strings. You're *not* going to iterate over all of them in *any* reasonable time frame. You just aren't. Accept it.

Comment: What exactly is your task? Maybe it would be possible to reverse the problem and find another solution.

Comment: Hey if you find a way to generate a `10^24` combinations per second, you can find all length 100 combinations of a 2 character alphabet in just over 2 weeks!

Comment: You know there are 10^30 combinations, and you still think there's a fast solution??

Comment: Have you tried inventing and then using a quantum computer?

Comment: No it's only my second week learning python. I'll start working on that when two more weeks pass, and I'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks to the ones who didn't include sarcasm in the comments. I am still not quite able to connect theoretical time complexity with real-time coding in a good way. I'll try something else. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate strings of size `n` from an alphabet set size of `m`, you cannot do better than `Theta(m**n)` runtime (each of the `n` alphabets can be one of the `m` letters) using a sequential programming model.

The following recursive program is an implementation (in principle needs `O(n)` space due to recursion depth; technically we would need to use a list of strings for `str_so_far` because while strings are immutable in Python, lists are mutable):

```
def gen_strings(alpha_set, n):
    def gen_strings_helper(str_so_far, n_remaining):
        if n_remaining == 0:
            all_strings.append(str_so_far)
            return
        for c in alpha_set:
            gen_strings_helper(str_so_far + c, n_remaining - 1)

    all_strings = []
    gen_strings_helper('', n)
    return all_strings

>>> gen_strings(['a', 'b'], 3)
['aaa', 'aab', 'aba', 'abb', 'baa', 'bab', 'bba', 'bbb']
```

To speed this up, you should look into parallel programming models.

**However, if `n=100` and `m=26` (the set of lowercase English alphabets), your output will be `26**100` strings long!**